# Proof of Darboux's Theorem when the function has infinite derivatives at both endpoints.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

[image]

I have a question about the statement in the NOTE above. It says that the Darboux's Theorem is also valid when one or both the one-sided derivatives are infinite. So say $f_{+}'(a)=-\infty, f_{-}'(b)=\infty$, or either one of them is finite, then we can suppose that $f_{+}'(a)\lt k \lt f_{-}'(b)$, and define $g$ on $I=[a,b]$ by $g(x)=kx-f(x)$. Since $g$ is continuous on compact interval, it attains a maximum value on $I$. Since $g'(a)=k-f_{+}'(a)\gt 0$, the maximum cannot occur at $a$. Similarly, since $g'(b)=k-f_{-}'(b)\lt 0$, the maximum cannot occur at $b$. Therefore, $g$ attains its maximum at some interior point $c$, and $g'(c)=k-f'(c)=0$. Hence, we have $f'(c)=k$ for some $c\in I$.

However, I do not know how to prove this for the case when both of the one-sided derivatives are $\infty$ or $-\infty$. In fact, how can I even interpret the intermediate values in this case? I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me with this proof.

Comment: When one sided derivatives at the end points are infinite then also your inequalities regarding $g'(a), g'(b)$ hold and hence maximum is attained at an interior point which leads to $g'(c) = 0$. I don't see any problem due to the infinite derivatives at end points of the interval.

Comment: How do I say $f_+'(a)/lt k /lt f_-'(b)$, when $f_+'(a)=\infty, f_-'(b)=\infty,$ or $f_+'(a)=-\infty, f_-'(b)=-\infty$? Also if I set up $g$ as above, then don't I get the same signs for both $g'(a), g'(b)$?

Comment: You must understand that even in this case we must have $f'_{+}(a) \neq f'_{-}(b)$ so that both can't be same type of $\infty$. If one is $\infty$ the other has to be finite or $-\infty$ and vice-versa. This way we can fit the $k$ between these two values.

Comment: Check [this proof](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwi_iMyJ38bIAhUIbY4KHSL_A58&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ime.usp.br%2F~oliveira%2FDARBOUXPROPERTY.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEqvVxyt6bfdmHCY3e_85qwhh9-Xg).